# How to change the functionality of button as well as text of it

Tags: events, button, gridview, edit, state-management

I have an createuser page in which i have some field and submit button.

When i click on my submit button it will save details into database

aspx.cs code for createuser page:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebGallery"].ToString()))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM NewUser WHERE UserName = '" + tbName.Text + "'";

        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) // Means first name is already present
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "This user is already added!";
        }
        else if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            lblmsg.Visible = false;
            string username = tbName.Text;
            string pwd=tbPassword.Text;
            string Confirmpwd = tbConfirmPassword.Text;
            string Email = tbEmailID.Text;
            string department = ddlDepartment.SelectedValue;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into NewUser(UserName,Password,ConfirmPassword,EmailID,DepartmentName)values('" + tbName.Text + "','" + tbPassword.Text + "','"+tbConfirmPassword.Text+"','" + tbEmailID.Text + "','" + ddlDepartment.SelectedValue + "')";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", tbName.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", tbPassword.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DomainID", tbConfirmPassword.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailID", tbEmailID.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"RoleType", ddlDepartment.SelectedValue);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            con.Close();
            tbName.Text = "";
            tbPassword.Text = "";
            tbConfirmPassword.Text = "";
            tbEmailID.Text = "";
            tbName.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

now i have a search user page in which i have a textbox, gridview and search button when i enter name of any user and click on search button it will show user details inside gridview
now i have an edit link inside gridview what i want is when i click on edit link it will redirect to createuser page where in place of submit button i want to show update button and when i make changes and click on update button details for the selected user which i select from edit link of search user page will update. how can i do that

aspx page of search user

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
           <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" 
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/CreateUser.aspx?ID={0}" 
                HeaderText="Edit" NavigateUrl="~/CreateUser.aspx" Text="Edit"/>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

aspx.cs code:

```
protected void BindGrid()
{
    if ((tbSearchUser.Text.Length == 0))
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Search Box cannot be empty! Please put something to search.";
    }
    con.Open();
    string query = "Select * from NewUser where UserName like'" + tbSearchUser.Text + "'";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
protected void btnSearchUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BindGrid();
}
```

now i have an edit link inside gridview what i want is when i click on edit link it will redirect to createuser page where in place of submit button i want to show update button and when i make changes and click on update button details for the selected user which i select from edit link of search user page will update. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have done it work for me i guess it will also work for you guys as well

On my create user page i user Request.QueryString like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["buttonValue"]))
        {
                string btnValue = Request.QueryString["buttonValue"];
                if (btnValue == "Update")
                {
                    btnSubmit.Text = "Update";
                }
                else if (btnValue == "Submit")
                {
                    btnSubmit.Text = "Submit";
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("error");
                }
        }
            else
        {
                this.btnSubmit.Text = "Submit";
        }

        string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from NewUser where ID='" + ID + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt.Clear();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            tbid.Text = ID;
            tbName.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            tbPassword.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            tbConfirmPassword.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
            tbEmailID.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
            ddlDepartment.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

and on clik event of my button:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.btnSubmit.Text == "Submit")
    {
        this.Submit();
        //Response.Write("Submit");
    }
    else if (btnSubmit.Text == "Update")
    {
        this.Update();
        //Response.Write("Update");
    }
}
```

in this Submit is a function where insert query work and update is a function where update query work

and on my search page in my gridview i make some changes in my hyperlink like this

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" HeaderText="Edit" 
               DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/CreateUser.aspx?ID={0}&buttonValue=Update"
               NavigateUrl="~/CreateUser.aspx" Text="Edit" />
```

and it work for me